# Query for checking if phrases between delimiters exists in DB

Tags: php, mysql

Excuse the terrible question title.

I have this PHP string and want to check a MySQL database for the existence of any of its contents.

> Awanto 3/Makam/Lone

I want to check if any of the names in the string (i.e  Awanto 3, Makam OR Lone) exist in a table in my DB. There will never be a case where 'Awanto 3/Makam/Lone' exists but there will probably be a case where either 'Awanto 3', 'Makam' or 'Lone' exists.

Table name is 'artists', column that will be checked is 'artist'

I will be doing this for around hundreds of these queries every day and there are 2-3000 rows in the 'artists' table.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: Thanks for that - this kind of works. The only problem is that sometimes there may be a record in artists for 'Lone Ranger' which produces a match but the artist name in the string is actually 'Lone' so it is not an accurate match. I tried this query....... SELECT * FROM artists WHERE MATCH(artist) AGAINST ('Awanto 3/Makam/Lone').....is there any amendments to that query which would produced the desired result? Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the string parts between the delimiters are the complete artist, not only a part of it, I'd do something like

```
$search="Awanto 3/Makam/Lone";

//transforms this to "Awanto 3','Makam','Lone"
$list=str_replace('/',"','",mysql_real_escape_string($search, $dbconnection));
$sql="select * from artists where artist in ('$list')";
//query and fetch
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$parts = explode('/', $input); //split string on '/'

foreach ($parts as $artist) $where .= "artist='$artist' OR"; //build WHERE clause
$where = substr($where, 0, strlen($where)-3); //remove last OR

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM artists WHERE $where"); //resource
```

This is the simple approach of splitting the string on a delimiter and building a WHERE clause to use in the query.

Comment: We could use IN instead of OR. SELECT * FROM ARTISTS WHERE artist IN (Awanto 3, Makam, Lone)